# Reusing Connection string

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns

Please see the code below:

```
Namespace DataAccessGateway
    Public Class clsAudit
        Implements IAudit

        Private _ConString As String
        Private _Provider As String

        Public Sub New()
            _ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbConnection").ConnectionString
            _Provider = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbConnection").ProviderName
        End Sub

        Public Function AddAudit(ByVal tyDeletion As typeDeletion) As Integer Implements IAudit.AddAudit
            Dim intCount As Integer
            Dim objParameterValues As New clsParameterValues
            Dim iConnectionBLL As iConnectionBLL
            Dim tyInnkeeperPremises As New typeInnkeeperPremises
            Dim objCon As DbConnection
            Try
                Dim paramValues() As DbParameter
                objParameterValues = New clsParameterValues
                iConnectionBLL = New clsConnectionBLL()
                objCon = iConnectionBLL.getDatabaseTypeByDescription("AUDIT")
                Using objCon
                    Dim strSQL As String
                    strSQL = "INSERT INTO dbAudit (Reference) VALUES (@Reference)"
                    objParameterValues.AssignParameterValues("@Reference", tyDeletion.Reference, 1)
                    paramValues = objParameterValues.getParameterValues
                    intCount = clsDatabaseHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(objCon, CommandType.Text, strSQL, paramValues)
                End Using
                Return intCount
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return -1
            End Try
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

This code is called as part of a batch processing job i.e. it could be called ten million times in a day all at once.  The connection string for the audit database is stored in an encrypted database table i.e. tbl_database (getDatabaseTypeByDescription queries this table).  Therefore the database must be queried up to ten million times to get the same connection string ten million times.  Is it bad practice to put the connection string in a static variable or is there a better way?

I realise it would be better to put the connection string in the config file but I am hoping to be consistent.

Comment: The connection string is usually stored in application config file. Alternatively, it can be a registry setting. I've never seen an app where it would be stored in a database, cause then you need a connection string for that database, to get the connection string you want. Do you have a reason to not do things straight?

Comment: @Neolisk, thanks. The web application queries the database to get many connection strings. Is it possible to extract the connection string from the config file and load it into the app.config when the app starts up?

Comment: 'extract ... string from ... config file and load ... into ... app.config ...'. Config file and app.config are one thing, no? Please explain. Please also elaborate on multiple connection strings in your question.

Comment: @neolisk. I meant extract from the database and load into the config file.

Comment: See if this helps: [Read/Write App.Config File with .NET 2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14744/Read-Write-App-Config-File-with-NET-2-0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this answer isn't very specific to .NET, I'd actually recommend approach mentioned in [The Twelve-Factor App](http://www.12factor.net/), excerpt below taken from the section on [config](http://www.12factor.net/config).

> **Store Config in the Environment**
>
> The twelve-factor app stores config in environment variables (often shortened to env vars or env). Env vars are easy to change between deploys without changing any code; unlike config files, there is little chance of them being checked into the code repo accidentally; and unlike custom config files, or other config mechanisms...

The document is targeted more towards *apps*, but I think a similar approach would work nice here. You can make the call to the database to get the connection string once, and then store it in your process or app domain environment. This will also give you fairly good flexibility when it comes to testing as well.